# Text boxes blank after while loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

Why are my text boxes blank after my while loop?

If I remove the while loop the data then shows?

This is the form below.

```
<form name="form" method="post" action=""> 
<input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" />

<p><input type="text" name="res_veop_id" placeholder="Enter VEOP ID" required value="<?php echo $row["res_veop_id"]; ?>"/></p>

<p><select class="selectpicker" name="res_title">
    <option value="<?php echo $row["res_title"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["title_name"]; ?></option>
<?php
$title_count=1;
$title_sel_query="Select * from `tbl_title` ORDER BY `title_id` asc;";
$title_result = mysqli_query($con,$title_sel_query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($title_result)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row["title_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["title_name"]; ?></option>
<?php $title_count++; } ?>
    </select>

</p>
<p><input type="text" name="res_first_name" placeholder="Enter Firstname" required value="<?php echo $row["res_first_name"]; ?>"/></p>
<p><input type="text" name="res_last_name" placeholder="Enter Lastname" required value="<?php echo $row["res_last_name"]; ?>"/></p>
<p><input type="text" name="res_dob" placeholder="Enter Date of Birth" required value="<?php echo $row["res_dob"]; ?>"/></p>
```

Comment: Because `$row` only exists within the while loop. When the loop is finished, that array is destroyed. It's "out of scope".

Comment: How would I correct this please

Comment: You simply use a different variable for the while loop. Something else than `$row`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the variabel `$row` in your code to address the values, that shall be shown on the whole page.
In your while loop, you overwrite the variable `$row` in the loop head. Since it is a while loop it will run until $row is null. Therefore all following calls on $row will return nothing.

I suggest you rename the variable:

```
while($option = mysqli_fetch_assoc($title_result)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $option["title_id"]; ?>"><?php echo 
$option["title_name"]; ?></option>
<?php $title_count++; } ?>
```

Comment: Good eye on the overwrite of `$row`. I noticed the out of scope issue straight away, but missed that one. +1 from me :)

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick.I did't think the variable $row was causing this.

Comment: @MatthewWeaver If this answer solved your issue, please check the checkmark on the left side of this answer. It's a way of showing your appreciation to the person that helped you out and makes sure your question doesn't remain unanswered forever :)